# Alternative or workaround for css property 'filter: xray;'

Tags: css, image, filter, deprecated

I have come across the scenario that I need to display xray of perticular image of webpage.

So I was using css property `filter: xray;`, which is working perfectly with IE8. But for modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox or even IE11/Edge, it seems doesn't support this property-value.

I dig into this more and I found like upto IE9 it is supporting. But nowhere I found on internet like this property value pair is deprecated or obsolete.

I need any solution on this so i can show xray of image on webpages. Any alternative for this also acceptable.

Below is sample code that is working upto IE9
`<img src="imagepath.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="filter: xray;" />`

Note: above code will not work if you running file from folder directly, it should require http protocol to reflect effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same functionality can be achieve by using combination of standard CSS filter property values as below:

**IE8:** `filter: xray;`

**Modern Browsers (i.e. Chrome, Firefox):** `filter: invert(100%) grayscale(100%);`

both produces equivalent output.